# How do I make the app allow incoming network connections with SwiftNIO?

Tags: ios, swift-nio

I am using [MicroExpress](https://github.com/NozeIO/MicroExpress) to create a web server in a `SwiftUI` app. I can connect to the server when I am running the app in Simulator, but I cannot make it work on my real device.

MicroExpress (based on `SwiftNIO`) creates a Webserver on the iPhone and shall expose an API in the local network.

I think I need to add a capability or something, but I cannot find the network capability nor a setting to allow incoming network connections in `Xcode 11` under `Signing & Capabilities`.

How do I make the app allow incoming network connections?

**EDIT**

I have already added `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to allow `HTTP` if that is necessary. I am connecting over `HTTP` at the moment.

Comment: Are you connecting to your server over HTTPS? If not, you need to add an exception to TLS (but don't, use a https server)

Comment: I did add "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to allow HTTP if that was / is necessary. I am connecting over HTTP at the moment

Comment: Then it should work. There's no additional entitlement required for network activity

Comment: Also for incoming network requests? Which domain do I need to add since the iPhone acts as a server?

Comment: I don't really know about that :/ If you're working over HTTP it might be disallowed entirely, Apple really doesn't like nonsecure loads. Again, dont know.

Comment: This is about incoming I/O processed by NIO directly, which is unrelated to ATS.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right IP address for the device on your local network?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure! Correct port and correct IP address :) I use LAN Scan by https://debookee.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the [tutorial](http://www.alwaysrightinstitute.com/nio-on-the-client/) and I think you need to bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. Doesn't have to do with capabilities nor ATS.

Comment: Great that works thank you very much! I don't know why I missed that!

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks.